# How can I retrieve information from AWS SDK with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, aws-sdk

I am trying to retrieve information with AWS SDK using TypeScript. In Python it was very easy, but I can't figure out how to do this with TypeScript. As you can see, I get the correct information and output it to the console using `console.log(data.Outpost?.OutpostArn)`.
But how can I return the `data.Outpost?.OutpostArn` from this class? I only get back a `response` from which I cannot extract the data.

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

class Outpost {
  outpostId: string;
  region: string;
  constructor(outpostId: string, region: string) {
    (this.outpostId = outpostId), (this.region = region);
    AWS.config.update({ region: this.region });
  }
  GetOutpostArn() {
    const OutpostArnData = new AWS.Outposts().getOutpost(
      { OutpostId: this.outpostId },
      function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else console.log(data.Outpost?.OutpostArn); // successful response
      }
    );
    debugger;
    return OutpostArnData;
  }
}

const outpostData = new Outpost(
  'op-0e32dade1930682b8',
  'us-west-2'
).GetOutpostArn();

console.log(outpostData);
```

Output:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-152:~/FirstTypeScriptCDK$ ts-node lib/outpost.ts 
arn:aws:outposts:us-west-2:280066404755:outpost/op-0e32dade1930682b8
```

and this is the response:

```
<ref *1> Request {
  domain: null,
  service: Service {
    config: Config {
      credentials: [SharedIniFileCredentials],
      credentialProvider: [CredentialProviderChain],
      region: 'us-west-2',
      logger: null,
      apiVersions: {},
      apiVersion: null,
      endpoint: 'outposts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
      httpOptions: [Object],
      maxRetries: undefined,
      maxRedirects: 10,
      paramValidation: true,
      sslEnabled: true,
      s3ForcePathStyle: false,
      s3BucketEndpoint: false,
      s3DisableBodySigning: true,
      s3UsEast1RegionalEndpoint: 'legacy',
      s3UseArnRegion: undefined,
      computeChecksums: true,
      convertResponseTypes: true,
      correctClockSkew: false,
      customUserAgent: null,
      dynamoDbCrc32: true,
      systemClockOffset: 0,
      signatureVersion: 'v4',
      signatureCache: true,
      retryDelayOptions: {},
      useAccelerateEndpoint: false,
      clientSideMonitoring: false,
      endpointDiscoveryEnabled: undefined,
      endpointCacheSize: 1000,
      hostPrefixEnabled: true,
      stsRegionalEndpoints: 'legacy',
      useFipsEndpoint: false,
      useDualstackEndpoint: false
    },
    isGlobalEndpoint: false,
    endpoint: Endpoint {
      protocol: 'https:',
      host: 'outposts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
      port: 443,
      hostname: 'outposts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
      pathname: '/',
      path: '/',
      href: 'https://outposts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/'
    },
    _events: { apiCallAttempt: [Array], apiCall: [Array] },
    MONITOR_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: EVENTS_BUBBLE],
    CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE: [Function: CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE],
    _clientId: 1
  },
  operation: 'getOutpost',
  params: { OutpostId: 'op-0e32dade1930682b8' },
  httpRequest: HttpRequest {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/outposts/op-0e32dade1930682b8',
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'aws-sdk-nodejs/2.1151.0 linux/v17.4.0 callback',
      'X-Amz-Content-Sha256': 'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855',
      'Content-Length': 0,
      Host: 'outposts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
      'X-Amz-Date': '20220610T082425Z',
      Authorization: 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAWRW4PGALHIBCPTWT/20220610/us-west-2/outposts/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=44ed28c50dca07327c0bb252b7897ab43b81ec53aef26ee8c20cffb2426239f3'
    },
    body: '',
    endpoint: {
      protocol: 'https:',
      host: 'outposts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
      port: 443,
      hostname: 'outposts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
      pathname: '/',
      path: '/',
      href: 'https://outposts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/',
      constructor: [Function]
    },
    region: 'us-west-2',
    _userAgent: 'aws-sdk-nodejs/2.1151.0 linux/v17.4.0 callback',
    stream: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 6,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [Array],
      outputSize: 542,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: false,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: null,
      _header: 'GET /outposts/op-0e32dade1930682b8 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: aws-sdk-nodejs/2.1151.0 linux/v17.4.0 callback\r\n' +
        'X-Amz-Content-Sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 0\r\n' +
        'Host: outposts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com\r\n' +
        'X-Amz-Date: 20220610T082425Z\r\n' +
        'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAWRW4PGALHIBCPTWT/20220610/us-west-2/outposts/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=44ed28c50dca07327c0bb252b7897ab43b81ec53aef26ee8c20cffb2426239f3\r\n' +
        'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/outposts/op-0e32dade1930682b8',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: [Function: emitRequestTimeout],
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'outposts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      didCallback: false,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    }
  },
  startTime: 2022-06-10T08:24:25.019Z,
  response: Response {
    request: [Circular *1],
    data: null,
    error: null,
    retryCount: 0,
    redirectCount: 0,
    httpResponse: HttpResponse {
      statusCode: undefined,
      headers: {},
      body: undefined,
      streaming: false,
      stream: null,
      _abortCallback: [Function: callNextListener]
    },
    maxRetries: 3,
    maxRedirects: 10
  },
  _asm: AcceptorStateMachine {
    currentState: 'send',
    states: {
      validate: [Object],
      build: [Object],
      afterBuild: [Object],
      sign: [Object],
      retry: [Object],
      afterRetry: [Object],
      send: [Object],
      validateResponse: [Object],
      extractError: [Object],
      extractData: [Object],
      restart: [Object],
      success: [Object],
      error: [Object],
      complete: [Object]
    }
  },
  _haltHandlersOnError: false,
  _events: {
    validate: [
      [Function (anonymous)],
      [Function],
      [Function: VALIDATE_REGION],
      [Function: BUILD_IDEMPOTENCY_TOKENS],
      [Function: VALIDATE_PARAMETERS]
    ],
    afterBuild: [
      [Function: COMPUTE_CHECKSUM],
      [Function],
      [Function: SET_CONTENT_LENGTH],
      [Function: SET_HTTP_HOST],
      [Function: SET_TRACE_ID]
    ],
    restart: [ [Function: RESTART] ],
    sign: [ [Function (anonymous)], [Function], [Function] ],
    validateResponse: [ [Function: VALIDATE_RESPONSE], [Function (anonymous)] ],
    send: [ [Function] ],
    httpHeaders: [ [Function: HTTP_HEADERS] ],
    httpData: [ [Function: HTTP_DATA] ],
    httpDone: [ [Function: HTTP_DONE] ],
    retry: [
      [Function: FINALIZE_ERROR],
      [Function: INVALIDATE_CREDENTIALS],
      [Function: EXPIRED_SIGNATURE],
      [Function: CLOCK_SKEWED],
      [Function: REDIRECT],
      [Function: RETRY_CHECK],
      [Function: API_CALL_ATTEMPT_RETRY]
    ],
    afterRetry: [ [Function] ],
    build: [ [Function: buildRequest] ],
    extractData: [ [Function: extractData], [Function: extractRequestId] ],
    extractError: [ [Function: extractError], [Function: extractRequestId] ],
    httpError: [ [Function: ENOTFOUND_ERROR] ],
    success: [ [Function: API_CALL_ATTEMPT] ],
    complete: [ [Function: API_CALL], [Function (anonymous)] ]
  },
  emit: [Function: emit],
  API_CALL_ATTEMPT: [Function: API_CALL_ATTEMPT],
  API_CALL_ATTEMPT_RETRY: [Function: API_CALL_ATTEMPT_RETRY],
  API_CALL: [Function: API_CALL],
  signedAt: 2022-06-10T08:24:25.025Z
}
```

Comment: This `(this.outpostId = outpostId), (this.region = region)` blew me away :) If you want to be concise, you could use [this feature](https://tsplay.dev/m3PPEW): `constructor(public outpostId: string, public region: string) {…`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `GetPostArnData` method you can return a `new Promise` and use `resolve` and `reject` to return the values. Try something like this:

Note: you can do a shorthand for constructors.

```js
class Outpost {
  constructor(public outpostId: string, public region: string) {
    AWS.config.update({ region: this.region });
  }
  GetOutpostArn() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      new AWS.Outposts().getOutpost(
        { OutpostId: this.outpostId },
        (err, data) => {
          if (err) reject(err); // an error occurred
          resolve(data.Outpost?.OutpostArn);
        }
      );
    });
  }
}

(async () => {
  const outpost = new Outpost("op-0e32dade1930682b8", "us-west-2");

  const data = await outpost.GetOutpostArn();
  console.log(data);
})();
```

Comment: I want to export this Class and import it in other Scripts. How can I adjust it, to return the ´´´const data´´´?

Comment: oh well you can just do `const outpost = new Outpost()` then `export default outpost` Then you use async await from where you imported the outpost.